# If $x^3=x+1$ then $x^{3n}=a_nx+b_n+c_n/x$, where $a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$, $b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+c_n$,$c_{n+1}=a_n+c_n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^3=x+1$ then $x^{3n}=a_nx+b_n+c_n/x$, where $a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$, $b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+c_n$,$c_{n+1}=a_n+c_n$.

I am not sure how to solve this, it seems like this statement is true for $x^3$ and $x^6$ when $a_1=0$, $b_1=x$ and $c_1=x$, but not $x^9$. Do I need to keep checking different possibilities regarding values of $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$ or is there a simpler way to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried induction? 

Update: I managed to solve it using induction; let me know if you want any hints

Comment: @Alan Hey, so do you take $x^{3(n+1)}=(a_n+b_n)x +(a_n+b_n+c_n)+(a_n+c_n)/x$

Comment: I think how the induction should be done is you write $$x^{3(n+1)} = x^3 x^{3n},$$ and then use the assumption that $x^{3n} = a_n x + b_n + c_n/x$ (substitute this assumption into the above equation for $x^{3n}$). Then, you want to show that this implies that $x^{3(n+1)}$ equals to the expression you sent.

Comment: When $n=1$ you get$$x^3=\color{red}{a_1x}+\color{blue}{b_1}+\color{green}{\frac{c_1}x}=\color{red}{x}+\color{blue}{1}\implies a_1=1,b_1=1,c_1=0$$

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!